# How can I fix an image into a box

Tags: html, css

I would like the portrait photo to be able to contain in the box without exceeding the box in below, can you give me a list of codes to put? check screenshot 1.

should also pay attention to the images in landscape so that it can keep the same position in screenshot 2.
[[image: screenshot 1]][[image: Screenshot 2]]

A minimum of code to fix my issue

Comment: What have you done so far? The question doesn't have the minimum requirements in order to make the reader understand.

Comment: Thank you for reply to my message. I have this box where when I have a portrait image this image exceeding to the screen. I want to fix the thumbnail portrait into the box without changing anything if it was a landscape photo.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure without your code but try setting image `max-height: 90%;`
 Add `width: auto;` too if needed,
Hope it helps.

Comment: It doesn’t work, can you tell me where I should put the code ? 
The columns or the image

Comment: You should put that code into the image css. If it doesnt work you can edit your post to add a code or send me a codepen link and I can try fixing